# re.sub part of string: (?: ...) mystery

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a character string:

```
temp = '4424396.6\t1\tk__Bacteria\tp__Firmicutes\tc__Erysipelotrichi\to__Erysipelotrichales'
```

And I need to get rid of tabulations only in between taxonomy terms.

I tried

```
re.sub(r'(?:\D{1})\t', ',', temp)
```

It came quite close, but also replaced the letter before tabs:

```
'4424396.6\t1\tk__Bacteri,p__Firmicute,c__Erysipelotrich,o__Erysipelotrichales'
```

I am confused as re documentation for `(?:...)` goes:

> ...the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after
>   performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

The last letter was within the parenthesis, so how could it be replaced?

PS

I used `re.sub(r'(?<=\D{1})(\t)', ',', temp)` and it works perfectly fine, but I can't understand what's wrong with the first regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text matched by `(?:...)` does not form a *capture group*, as does `(...)`, and therefore cannot be referred to later with a backreference such as `\1`.  However, it's still part of the overall match, and is part of the text that `re.sub()` will replace.

The point of non-capturing groups is that they are slightly more efficient, and may be required in uses such as `re.split()` where the mere existence of capturing groups will affect the output.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html), `(?:...)` specifies a *non-capturing group*. It explains:

> Sometimes you’ll want to use a group to collect a part of a regular expression, but aren’t interested in retrieving the group’s contents.

What this means is that anything that matches the `...` expression (in your case, the preceding letter) will not be captured as a group *but will still be part of the match*. The only thing special about this is that you won't be able to access the part of the input captured by this group using `match.group`:

> Except for the fact that you can’t retrieve the contents of what the group matched, a non-capturing group behaves exactly the same as a capturing group

In contrast, `(?<=...)` is a *positive lookbehind assertion*; the regular expression will check to make sure any matches are preceded by text matching `...`, but won't capture that part.